# integration problem using limits from zero to infinity

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{6}xe^{\frac{-x}{6}}dx$$.

What is the value of the integral?

I got (1/6) but I think the answer is 6.

Comment: Mind sharing how you got $\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: This integral equals $\frac 16\mathfrak L(x,1/6)$ where $\mathfrak L$ denotes the Laplace transform. Do you know the Laplace transform of $f(x)=x$ ?

Comment: Surely Laplace transforms are totally overkill? Integration by parts doesn't suffice?

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts works, with $u = x$, $dv = e^{-x/6}$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac 16 xe^{-x/6} dx= -xe^{-x/6}|_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty -e^{-x/6} dx= \int_0^\infty -e^{-x/6} dx = 6$$

Thanks to Alfred Yerger for the idea.

Comment: Yeah. I goofed... Thank you for posting the correct answer.

Comment: how did u solve (-x*e^-x/6) where x varies from 0 to inf? when you substitute inf dont you get a inf/inf form??

Comment: @Victor428 , When I substitute $\infty$, I get $e^{-\infty}$ which is $0$.

Comment: @Victor428 As you go to infinity, the $e^{-x}$ term tends to $0$ faster than the $x$ term goes to infinity. So their product tends to zero.

Comment: I used L hospitals rule to fix that....anyways thanks guys...